# Accuracy Decreasing with higher epochs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am a newbie to Keras and machine learning in general. I'm trying to build a binary classification model using the Sequential model. After some experimenting, I saw that on multiple runs(not always) I was getting a an accuracy of even 97% on my validation data in the second or third epoch itself but this dramatically decreased to as much as 12%. What is the reason behind this ? How do I fine tune my model ? 
Here's my code -

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(6,size)))
model.add(Dense(6,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.35))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y,epochs=60,batch_size=40,validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: How is you loss doing? also increasing?

Comment: One word: Overfitting

Comment: As Matias mentioned above, it's the case of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting): the more data you provide to the model, the more noise it generates and subsequently fails to maintain accuracy. Because each layer is initialized with randomized weights, each time you run the model from clean state, it produces different results. If you added the input data sample to the question, it might help us dig a bit deeper, because it's hard right now to judge from the code alone (except that it's quite simple) what could go wrong.

Comment: The loss always goes down to around 0.6. Would increasing the amount of input data avoid overfitting  ? Each data sample is a 2D array of floating point numbers of the form (6,50)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to me, you can take into consideration the following factors.

1. **Reduce your learning rate** to a very small number like 0.001 or even 0.0001.
2. Provide **more data**.
3. Set **Dropout rates** to a number like 0.2. **Keep them uniform across the network**.
4. Try **decreasing the batch size**.
5. Using appropriate optimizer: You may need to experiment a bit on this. Use different optimizers on the same network, and **select an optimizer which gives you the least loss**.

If any of the above factors work for you, please let me know about it in the comments section.

Comment: I have solved my issues using point 4. THanks

Comment: Point 3 was good for me. To start with high learning rate, and reduce after few epoch, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue, I solved by changing the optimizer from RMSprop to adam. I also reduced the learning rate and added dropout after each fully connected layers. If your FC layers have small number of neurons then adding dropout does not make a major difference.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the learning rate (like 0.001 or 0.0001) and add batch normalization after every convolution layer.

Comment: Your answer seems to repeat one provided earlier. You may want to stress new information you wanted to share next time. E.g. bolding 'batch normalization' in this case.